# Getting numeric value instead of Date value at RunTime

Tags: delphi, date, datetimepicker

I'm Getting numeric value of "DateTimePciker.Date" at run time. But i want value like '08/10/2012'. How to get DATE value instead of Numeric value?

show picture of runtime:

---

[image]

Comment: Try .AsString instead of .Date property.

Comment: Do `DateToStr(...)` in the watch, and make sure 'Allow function calls' is checked.

Comment: .As String not usable. would i include any unit or class for that?

Comment: Since Delphi 2010 there's already a [debugger vizualizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Debugger_Visualizers#TDateTime_Visualizer) which shows the string representation of the `TDatetime` value.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand it display DATE in correct format but value is already "41188.668981".

Comment: If you only want the date part of the TDateTime float type, call `vEmpDetailRec.DOJ := Trunc(dtpDOJ.Date);`

Comment: Without Trunc() function value is : 41188.668981
After using Trunc() func value is : 41188, Only Decimal part is removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TDateTime` is not shown as you expect in old Delphi versions. `TDateTime` is a float type, and that's exactly normal for the debugger to display the float value. You might consider converting it using `DateTimeToStr()` if you need to see the value.

Comment: Or `FormatDateTime('dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss.zzz')` if you need milliseconds.

Comment: Function DateTimeToStr() and FormateDateTime() returns date as String, but i have to save in TDateTime format.

Comment: `TDateTime` is virtually the same as `Double`. When you read a `double` value into a `TDateTime`, it becomes a time stamp.

Answer (score 6):

The Delphi `TDateTime` type is described like this in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.TDateTime):

> The **TDateTime** class inherits a val data member--declared as a double--that holds the date-time value. The integral part of a **TDateTime** value is the number of days that have passed since December 30, 1899. The fractional part of a **TDateTime** value is the time of day.

In `System.pas` the type is declared like this:

```
TDateTime = type Double;
```

Your value of `41188.668981` is a perfectly valid `TDateTime` value. It represents a point in time that is `41188.668981` days after the Delphi date time epoch. Call `DateTimeToStr()` to convert that into human readable form. If you only want to see the date part, and don't want to see the time, use `DateToStr()` instead.

```
Writeln(DateTimeToStr(41188.668981));
Writeln(DateToStr(41188.668981));
```

which results in this output

```
06/10/2012 16:03:19
06/10/2012
```

In summary, your code is functioning exactly as expected. The value you see is exactly what you would expect for a `TDateTime`. If you need to represent the date time value in textual format, use the appropriate conversion function.

Comment: Your edit makes the question clear. I think the question has been answered. Is that right?

Comment: Delphi date time epoch being 01/01/1900. (inclusive)